# MusiXTeX within LaTeX does not insert space before first note

Tags: spacing, musixtex

to make my problem visible, I have created following simple file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\begin{document}
\begin{music} 
\startpiece
\notes\nq{hgf}\enotes\alaligne
\notes\nq{hgf}\enotes
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

Processing this with `latex file` `musixflx file` `latex file` gives a rather nasty output, because between the clef and the first note in the first line, there is nearly no space. The problem does not occur in subsequent lines, and it does not occur when using `\startextract ... \endextract` instead of `\startpiece ... \endpiece`, but this is no option for `\startextract` allows only one line of music.
   Has anybody any idea, why this happen, and how to fix it?

Best regards,
Volker

Comment: I think the difference is caused by the different definition of \startpiece and \startextract in musixtex.tex, where the latter ends with \empty\addspace\afterruleskip, whereas this is written without the \empty before the \lastbarpos in the definition of \startpiece.

Answer (score 1):

Please try add something like this before `\startpiece`

```
\hsize150mm
```

[image]

> Below is the updated version of my answer:

If you extend your scores to the length of acutal musical lines, it will shown correctly. However if you'd like to only exhibit what in your example file, you can use `\sk` or `\noteskip` to forward one note's distance.`\hsk` for half note skip.

`\qsk` for one note head width, `\tqsk`,`\hqsk`,`\qqsk` for two third, half thirds, or one quarter. `\bqsk`,`\btsk`,`\bhsk` to skip backwardly.

Importantly, you'd need package `xspace` too, or else the bars at the end of the line will scatter apart.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{xspace}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\begin{document}
\begin{music} 
%\hsize150mm % \hsize moves all the lines horizontally to the right 
\startpiece
\notes\hsk\nq{hgf}\enotes\alaligne
\notes\bhsk\nq{hgf}\enotes
\endpiece
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

I tridd my best, I suggest you still wait for the better answers, I am also curious to see the professional anwser! Jesus bless!

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the answer! Yes, there is now more space between clef and first note, but still the first line does not look like the following - what I do expect.

Comment: @Volker I update the answer, you can keep the question and wait for better and professional answers, I am curious too.

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference comes from the `\afterruleskip` extra space added after each bar. The firstline does not have this space, so you can just add it manually:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\begin{document}
\begin{music} 
\startpiece \addspace\afterruleskip
\notes\nq{hgf}\enotes\alaligne
\notes\nq{hgf}\enotes
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

Then the notes on the two lines are aligned.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! Yes, now it looks as expected! Yet, I still think, this extra coding should not be necessary.

Comment: Yet, in musixtex official documentation, almost all `\startpiece` are followed with `\addspace\afterruleskip`, so I think it is necessary.